# Shifting text around in a sentence via R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, text

I have an R dataframe with movie names like so:

```
Shawshank Redemption, The
Godfather II, The
Band of Brothers
```

I would like to display these names as:

```
The Shawshank Redemption
The Godfather II
Band of Brothers
```

Can anyone help with how to do a check each row of the dataframe to see if there is a 'The' after a comma (like) above, and if there is, shift it to the front of the sentence?

Comment: You have two "The" after comma, but you only shifted the second one. So is it both or only one?

Comment: I updated the way the sentences are printed out in R.  See if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
df$movies2 = gsub("^([\\w\\s]+),*\\s*([Tt]he*($|(?=\\s\\(\\d{4}\\))))", "\\2 \\1", df$movies, perl = TRUE)
```

**Result:**

```
> df
                            movies                         movies2
1 Shawshank Redemption, The (1994) The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
2                Godfather II, The                The Godfather II
3                 Band of Brothers                Band of Brothers
4               Dora, The Explorer              Dora, The Explorer
5             Kill Bill Vol. 2 The            Kill Bill Vol. 2 The
6                  ,The Highlander                 ,The Highlander
7                   Happening, the                   the Happening
```

**Data:**

```
df = data.frame(movies = c("Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)", 
                           "Godfather II, The", 
                           "Band of Brothers",
                           "Dora, The Explorer", 
                           "Kill Bill Vol. 2 The", 
                           ",The Highlander",
                           "Happening, the"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Notes:**

The goal of the entire regex is to group the first part (part before `,`) and the second part ('The' after `,` and only when it's at the end or before `(year)`) into separate capture groups which I can swap with `\\2` and `\\1`

- `^([\\w\\s]+)` matches any word character or spaces one or more times starting from the beginning of the string
- `,*\\s*` matches comma and space both zero or more times
- `[Tt]he*` matches "The" or "the" zero or more times
- Notice that it is followed by `($|(?=\\s\\(\\d{4}\\)))` which matches the "end of string", `$`, or a positive lookahead, which checks whether the previous pattern is followed by `\\s\\(\\d{4}\\)`
- `\\s\\(\\d{4}\\)` matches a space and `(4 digits)` *including the parentheses*. Double backslashes are needed to escape a single backslash
- So `([Tt]he*($|(?=\\s\\(\\d{4}\\))))` matches "The" or "the" either at the end of string or if it is followed by `(4 digits)`
- Everything in parentheses are capture groups, so `\\2 \\1` swaps the first capture group, `([\\w\\s]+)`, with the second, `([Tt]he*($|(?=\\s\\(\\d{4}\\))))`
- Now, since "The" is only matched zero or more times by `[Tt]he*`, if a string doesn't have "The" in it, an empty string gets swapped, with `\\1`, which returns the original string.

Comment: Can you explain the regex going on in `gsub()`    What if at the the movie titles looked more like `"Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)"' and I wanted to leave the (1994) at the end, and move 'The' to the front like you have it?  Possible?

Comment: What about "Dora, The Explorer"? do you also want it to become "The Explorer Dora"? or do you only want to leave years alone?

Comment: The Dora one in fine.  Just want to leave the years where they are (at the end) and move "The" to the front so it reads The Shawshank Redemption (1994) instead of Shawshank Redemption, The (1994).

Comment: @ckdf14 Added some notes for reference. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @ckdf14 Do consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote button

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
#create a vector of movies
x=c("Shawshank Redemption, The", "Godfather II, The", "Band of Brothers")

#use grep to find those with ", The" at the end
the.end=grep(", The$",x)

#trim movie titles to remove ", The"
trimmed=strtrim(x[the.end],nchar(x[the.end])-5)

#add "The " to the beginning of the trimmed titles
final=paste("The",trimmed)

#replace the trimmed elements of the movie vector
x[the.end]<-final

#take a look
x
```

Note that this doesn't remove ", The" from anywhere in the name other than the end... I think that's the behaviour that you want. It will also miss any "The" without the comma, or lower case "the". To see what I mean, try this as your initial movie vector:

```
#create a vector of movies
x=c("Shawshank Redemption, The", "Godfather II, The", "Band of Brothers",
    "Dora, The Explorer", "Kill Bill Vol. 2 The", ",The Highlander",
    "Happening, the")
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work, but is it possible to do it more arbitrarily?  Meaning, if I pulled down a list of movies from a database, I would like to check each of the movies to see if there is a 'The' in the last position, and if there is, shift it to the front.

Comment: Well here, "x" is just an example, but if you downloaded a list of movies and passed a vector of their names to this code, it would work in the same way. 

You'd have to figure out how to get the names out of the downloaded list and into the vector, but you'd have to do that to pass them to R anyway.

To make this code more robust, you could pass the output from this code to a second copy of the same code, where you replace ", The$" in grep() with, say, ", the$" or " The$" (to catch the shortcomings I described at the end of the answer). Converting the code to a function could allow that.

Comment: So, I can take each like int he dataframe column corresponding to the movie name, place them in a vector, and then run the code above.  I think that'll work.  Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. If you do this: `x <- df$moviename` you'll have vector x that you can pass directly to the code above.

Comment: It doesnt work for some reason when I pass the column name to be a vector.  Keeps the same format.

Comment: Hmm... can you post some data to show me what you're seeing?

One thing to check is the vector's format. When you read a file into R as a dataframe, strings are often coerced to the "factor" type rather than "character", which could be causing problems for you.

Comment: I cant figure out how to place a nice example of the code block from R output, but it does show that `x` is a <character>

Comment: `> typeof(x)
[1] "character"`

Comment: To be clear, if you use `df[1]` to subset, it won't work - you need to specify the dimension you're subsetting with a comma. Use `df[,1]` or `df$moviename` instead. This also won't work if the column is coded as a factor - try `x <- as.character(df$moviename)`

Comment: I tried all of those methods and it didn't word.  It still prints out the same way.  Is there another way to put each title in a vector?  I tried `as.vector()` but that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: Without a workable example, I'm at a loss for what to suggest here. I doubt we can resolve it in the comments section - I think it would be best if you edited your original question to show us the dataframe that you're working with (e.g. post the return from `head(df)`, possibly also `str(df)`), and give the code for what you're trying. Really, you should have provided that in the beginning. My answer was designed to work off what you gave us - since it isn't working for you, it's even more important that we see what you're actually doing, so we can help you.

Comment: I don't yet have enough reputation to comment on someone else's posts, but @UseR's is more flexible, and does in one line what took several in my own answer. That's the power of a workable example and detailed knowledge of regular expressions syntax!

Comment: I think I see the issue. Some of the lines have a date at the end of them similar to `Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)`  I want to leave the data as is and move 'The' to the front as you did above

Comment: This is why it's **critical** that you precisely explain your problem and provide example data. @UseR and I both gave answers predicated on the information that you gave us - you said that the string ends with the pattern that you're trying to find and replace. Unfortunately, our solutions won't work on strings that don't follow that pattern. To improve your questions (and the answers that you get) in the future, the more examples you give, the better the outcome will be - especially if you provide data and any code that you've already tried.